# How can I append "ls" output to the end of a previous line in text file w/ space in between?

Tags: bash, ls

How do I append `ls` output to the end of a line in a text file rather than a separate line at the end of the file?

For example, when I do:

```
ls ${OUTDIR}/{SUB}/rh.*fs6.nii.gz >> practice.txt
ls ${OUTDIR}/{SUB}/lh.*fs6.nii.gz >> practice.txt
```

It comes out in the text file as:

```
user/sb/sub/rh.5432.fs6.nii.gz
user/sb/sub/lh.5432.fs6.nii.gz
```

But I need it to look like this:

```
user/sb/sub/rh.5432.fs6.nii.gz user/sb/sub/lh.5432.fs6.nii.gz
```

I need the fix in bash and have tried `-n` after `ls`.

Comment: What other research was done on this topic? Does this solve the issue? https://superuser.com/a/893329/1059343

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: What did you expect `ls -n` would do?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
awk -v v="$(echo `ls -C ${OUTDIR}/${SUB}/lh.*fs6.nii.gz`)" '
  BEGIN{printf >> "practice"}
  NR>1{print line}
  {line=$0}
  END{print line, v}
' practice.txt > p2.txt ; mv p2.txt practice.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use *special pattern characters* inclosed in `[...]` to match both `l` and `r` which would cause the single `ls` command to match both `lh` and `rh` using `[lr]h`. In your case:

```
ls ${OUTDIR}/{SUB}/[lr]h.*fs6.nii.gz >> practice.txt
```

(**note:** you appear to be missing the `'$'` before `${SUB}` in your expression if you intend to use `SUB=sub`)

Comment: What's the point of using ls here, why not just echo? And *ls command to match both lh and rh* sounds wrong, since shell performs the pathname expansion

Comment: Well, he wanted to `ls` both sets of patterns and join them with a space. This was the simplest way of turning both `ls` into a single `ls` that would result in space separate output.

Comment: But there is no point in using ls for this, at least you could have noted that

Comment: Maybe I'm reading it wrong, but `ls ${OUTDIR}/{SUB}/rh.*fs6.nii.gz >> practice.txt` certainly looks like he is attempting to redirect filenames resulting from the `ls` command to `practice.txt`?  (Oh, this is creating the file in the format he desires rather than manipulating the contents of the file after-the-fact, maybe that is where our confusion is)

Comment: OP says *have tried -n after ls.* (like echo -n), from this I gather he wants to print all matching files in a single line separated by spaces, and he thinks `ls` performs the pathname expansion -which is not true-, that's why he uses ls

Comment: Yes, that is completely unclear. If this isn't what he is looking for, then the question is asking something completely different than it appears to be. `ls -n` would make no sense at all unless they want a `-n, --numeric-uid-gid`.

Comment: @oguzismail I think I get what you are saying, the `ls` is irrelevant to producing the space separated listing and it could be done better with a `for` loop and outputting the files space separated that way (if that's what he is after -- I agree -- and do it in a subshell and just redirect the output of the subshell once)

Answer (score 0):

Given your example, this command will have the effect you're looking for:

```
echo "${OUTDIR}/{SUB}"/{r,l}h.*fs6.nii.gz >> practice.txt
```

That is, after the shell expands the command line parameters the command becomes:

```
echo user/sb/sub/rh.5432.fs6.nii.gz user/sb/sub/lh.5432.fs6.nii.gz >> practice.txt
```

This might not work for other cases you want to support,
notably when the file patterns don't match a file.
When the pattern doesn't match a file,
the shell doesn't expand it, for example `echo foo*` stays just that.

If you want to support that case, you can use a loop:

```
{
    padding=
    for path in "${OUTDIR}/{SUB}"/{r,l}h.*fs6.nii.gz; do
        [[ -e "$path" ]] || continue
        printf "$padding$path"
        padding=' '
    done
    echo
} >> practice.txt
```